# Get row and column of a regex match from a document

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I am writing a test to find if the doctype is in the correct location. The doctype should be on the first line on the 0th column in a document, if it is found anywhere else, I want to get the location for the doctype and send it in the error message. I can't do it with the usual .exec method because it returns the index without information about rows and columns.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

A playground I created to try and achieve this...

```js
var content = `<p>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
`
var regexp= /(<!doctype\s+(html)\s*(\s+system\s+"about:legacy-compat")?\s*?>)/gi

var match = regexp.exec(content);
if (match) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```

Comment: I could split it line by line and do an iterative search I suppose... wondering if anyone has any better ideas...

Comment: I'd suggest to learn row/column indexes based on the position returned by `RegExp.exec`. For that you'll need to reverse-iterate characters and count all occurrences of `\n` before the matched position.

Comment: I think this is possible with a regex, but the necessity of it being on the first line and no where else makes it less intuitive to perform completely with a regex. Better to just check the first line first, and then the rest of the lines if the first line checks out. It should be computationally cheaper too. Is there a reason you don't want to use iterative searching?